# Group open screens in tab sheet in Vaadin 14

Tags: java, vaadin14

How can I group my screen openings on a sheet of tabs?

Example: I have the Person screen open and I need to edit some Documents fields without leaving the Person screen and open a new tab for Documents

[image]

This is always within the same browser tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an opt-in option for opening multiple application views in tabs within the app, for quick comparison or navigation between data. You enable this feature by setting `MainLayout.navigationTabs` to true.